# Bad if I use a Higher power adapter for a keyboard instrument requiring lower power and amps?

Tags: power-supply, power

Can I use a 13.5VDC 1a power supply for a keyboard that requires a 10VDC 800ma power supply without ruining the keyboard? I was told that the keyboard would only draw the power and amperage it needed and the higher DC voltage and amperage from the power supply would NOT ruin the keyboard. IS THIS TRUE?

Comment: Voltages must be the same, power supply current might be higher.

Answer (score 2):

Not completely.  Higher amps on the adapter is OK, higher volts is not.  Higher voltage can definitely cause damage.

The adapter attempts to supply a constant voltage, the connected device will draw whatever current that it requires at that voltage.  If the voltage is too high it can cause components to fail.  Things like voltage regulators may overheat by dissipating more power than they were designed to, capacitors may fail and leak, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Higher amperage, o.k. Higher voltage can damage the instrument.